How to realize streaming response from Ollama local LLM in the Streamlit App?
I'm a little confused in the documentation of the components. I need to implement a stream output from a local language model to a stream interface. I know that there is a new method st.write_stream, but I don't understand how to use it, because I get an error that my response from the language model is a string.
Some code:
from langchain import LLMChain, PromptTemplate
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.llms import Ollama
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager

callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
llm = Ollama(model=st.session_state.selected_model, callbacks=callback_manager)
    
initial_instruction = """You are a multifunctional chatbot created to help users. You must remember the context of the dialogue and provide the most accurate answers to the user's requests.
    """
    
prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["input", "chat_history"],
        template=f"""
        {initial_instruction}

        Chat history:
        {{chat_history}}

        User: {{input}}
        """.strip()
    )
    
st.session_state.llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template, memory=st.session_state.memory)

for message in st.session_state.messages:
    if message["role"] is "user":
        with st.chat_message(name = "user", avatar = "source/ai_user_2.png"):
            st.write(message["content"])
    
elif message["role"] is "assistant":
        with st.chat_message(name = "assistant", avatar = "source/ai_bot_2.png"):
            st.write(message["content"])
                
if prompt := st.chat_input(""):
    with st.chat_message(name="user", avatar="source/ai_user_2.png"):
        st.write(prompt)
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
    
    with st.chat_message(name="assistant", avatar="source/ai_bot_2.png"):

        streamed_response = st.write_stream(st.session_state.llm_chain.run(input=prompt))
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": streamed_response})

Gets error:
StreamlitAPIException: st.write_stream expects a generator or stream-like object as input not <class 'str'>. Please use st.write instead for this data type.
How I can stream response?

You need a runnable/generator for this. Try this:
streamed_response = st.write_stream(st.session_state.llm_chain.stream(input=prompt))
Read the documentation properly.

It's weird but it just leads me to the output of the JSON object in the chat area. The format is something like this: { "input": "Hello" "chat_history": [ 0: "HumanMessage(content='Hello')" 1: "AIMessage(content= 'Hello. Let's start')" ] "text" : "Hello. Let's start" } Not stream process :(

Have you used llm_chain.stream?

It's not work for me :( I find method to use OpenAI Langchain class for streaming, but the result of the answers in logic does not satisfy me. I need to use streaming with a chain

Ok. It worked for me many times. Not sure why its not for you. But this is the only way for streaming for this use case. Try to read the documentation and debug.
